# How do I get parameter in todos_controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to write a todo list app in rails4, and the todo list app will look like

```
1.task one    
  *todo 1    
  *todo 2    
2.task two    
  *todo 1    
  *todo 2
```

So I want to demo all the things in the task's index, which also fetch their tasks' todos separately. Now, my url will look like `project/1/tasks`, and this will show all the things I need.

I don't know how to do it. I have two tables: `tasks` and `todos`. So, currently I have a thought, which renders 'todos/index' in 'tasks/index', so I need to pass a parameter `task_id` in order to fetch the todos separately.

How do I get parameter task_id in todos_controller? And I will not access it by url, I will render it in task's index view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use nested resources:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

For example:

```
# routes.rb
resources :tasks do
  resources :todos
end
```

And in your todos controller

```
# todos_controller.rb
def index
  @task = Task.find(params[:task_id])
  @todos = @task.todos
  # ...
end

def show
  @task = Task.find(params[:task_id])
  @todos = @task.todos.find(params[:id])
  # ...
end
```

Comment: here is the problem I already use the nested resources    
resources :projects  do
    resources :tasks
end
And I don't want to use a three-level nested resources.